# Why `(a-- > 0)` and `((a--) > 0)` are same?

Tags: c++, c, operators

The program is as

```
main()
{
int a=1;
if( a-- > 0)
   printf("AAAA");
else
   printf("BBBB");
}
```

Its output is `AAAA`
and if I use

```
main()
{
int a=1;
if( (a--) > 0)
   printf("AAAA");
else
   printf("BBBB");
}
```

then why again the output is `AAAA`.
`()` has more preference then `--` .

Comment: It might help you to think `a--` being implemented as `int postInc( int& a ) { int tmp = a;  a = a-1; return tmp }`, parenthesis do not *reevaluate* the variable either.

Comment: Fun fact: you can also say `(a --> 0)`, the parser doesn't care ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The postfix operator `--` has [higher precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence) than any boolean comparison operator.

What do you expect exactly? `a--` always evaluates to the value of `a` which is decremented after evaluation.

Comment: then it must be decremented the comparison will take place.

Comment: If you want decrementation use `--a`, not `a--`. `--a` decrements a and then evaluates to the new value of a. `a--` evaluates to the value of `a` before decrementing it.

Answer (score 2):

The postfix `--` operator **returns** the original value of the variable, even after decrementing it.

So yes, `a` **is** decremented before the comparison, but the result of the expression `a--` is **not** `a`, but the value `1`.

Comment: no, strictly speaking the increment must not necessarily take place before the comparison. The point where the increment operation itself takes place is only forced to be before the next sequence point, whenever this suits the compiler.

Comment: @Jens, good point. That explanation is going one level deeper though, I guess I just wanted to emphasise that if you accessed `a` again before the comparison, `a` would already be decremented.

Answer (score 0):

`--` decrements the value of a variable after it is used in the expression.

Comment: And `()` has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

The use of parentheses here doesn't have any effect on the code because the order of evaluation is the same with and without the parentheses.  You are correct that parentheses have higher precedence than --.  However, in this case the parentheses won't change the order of evaluation because you didn't group the operands in a different order than they'd evaluate naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link with all the [operator's precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence) in C++.